# use jquery to anchor to certain overlay div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

So I have a site, and on click I need it to show overlay div, plus scroll to certain div on that overlay div.

This is what I have:

```
$(".mcl-title").click(function() {
    $("body").addClass("modal-on");
    $(".overlay-container").show();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(".spm-mcl").offset().top}, 'slow');
});
```

So when the user clicks on .mcl-title, it shows the overlay-container, which covers the entire page, and I need it to move to .spm-mcl class in the middle of that overlay.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What about your current attempt is not working as you expect?

Comment: that code opens up the overlay, but doesnt scroll to the assigned div.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine, see this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d160vLqm/37/. Are you certain that your target element has the `spm-mcl`  class and are you certain that you do not have another element with that class higher up on the page? It will scroll to the first element with that class, notice in my example that it scrolls to the yellow div and not the red one which also has that class but is lower on the page

Comment: Ah, ok, the element is a `link`, see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are adding your event to a `link`. Default behaviour is to *navigate* to that anchor on the page which doesnt exist so you get the top of the page.

When you click:
`<a class="item_download button_large news-title" href="#spm-mcl">See More</a>`

It tries to navigate to an element with the ID `spm-mcl`. (You have not such element. You have an element with the `class` `spm-mcl`.

You need to call `event.preventDefault();` to cancel the default link behaviour.

Also, you can greatly simplify your code and use just one event handler for all the links like this:

#### [Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d160vLqm/38/)

```
<a class="item_download button_large news-title" data-scroll-target=".spm-mcl" href="#">See More</a>



$(document).on('click', '[data-scroll-target]', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // stop default link navigation
  var $this=$(this); // the clicked button
  var target=$this.data('scroll-target');
  $("body").addClass("modal-on");
  $(".overlay-container").show();
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(target).offset().top},
    'slow');
});
```

Comment: man, your jsFiddle perfectly displays what I'm trying to do, but doesn't work on my site. Maybe I need to restructure the js order or something.

Comment: @hkk I dont see the changes on your live site. Also, note that I have changed the `html` for the links to include `data-scroll-target=".spm-mcl"` which will tell the function which element to scroll to